# Create a SOAP based Web Service that stores data from request to database

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have been asked to create a SOAP based web service (company is typically Microsoft-centric and I will attempt to do this in Visual Studio/C#) which does the following:

1. Listens for a SOAP request from another system that will contain the values for 3 fields (report name, run date, user ID)
2. Logs the inbound SOAP request/outbound response to a SQL database table
3. Stores the 3 values sent in the inbound SOAP request to a database table

Can anybody point me in the right direction for how this should be done? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood your question, but you can create a symple API (web service) with project ASP.NET core web aplication.

On the Visual Studio 2017 updated - > File - > New Project - > Web - > ASP.NET core Web Aplication - > API.

If you return a serializable object, WebAPI will automatically send JSON or XML based on the Accept header that your client sends.

Create a class in the controller like this:

```
[Route("api/Client")]
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Client(string name, DateTime date, int id)
    {
        string return1 = "return1", return2 = "return2";

        return Ok(new { return1, return2});
    }
}
```

Your client can call this class by the url www.sample.com/api/client